# register_callback_query_handler в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть модуль handlers.py.

Пытаюсь сделать регистрацию в файл main.py . Работает всё, за исключением хендлера с выбором даты через календарь.Сам хендлер c календарем и выбором\записью даты работает.Просто не пойму как зарегистрировать и перенести

Пример:

```
dp.register_message_handler(process_start_command, commands=["start"])
dp.register_message_handler(help_command, commands=["help"])
dp.register_message_handler(answer_text, state=Promises.promis_text)
dp.register_callback_query_handler(answer_date,state=Promises.promis_date).
TypeError: answer_date() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback_data'
```

Но как засунуть callback_dat'у в него- так и не понял.

Вот сам хендлер.

```
# @dp.callback_query_handler(simple_cal_callback.filter())
async def answer_date(call: types.CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict, state: FSMContext):
    selected, date = await SimpleCalendar().process_selection(call, callback_data)
    if selected:
        await Promises.promis_date.set()
        await state.update_data(deadline=f'{date.strftime("%Y.%m.%d")}')
        data = await state.get_data()
        await db_admin.sql_add(data)
        await state.finish()
        if db_admin.sql_deadline(call.from_user.id)[0] < now.strftime("%Y.%m.%d"):
            await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, "Вы выбрали уже прошедшее время.Обещание не было создано")
            db_admin.sql_delete(call.from_user.id)
```

Comment: Госпади зачем? Чертов python hub studio! Просто делайте декораторы и всё, это же в разы понятнее и проще для восприятия

Comment: :))
А вы проницательны )
Но это задание мне дал мой наставник , для навыка правильного "код-стайла".
В целом я ему изначально и сказал что ерундой занимаюсь . 
Но чем богаты ...)

Comment: И в дополнение искренне советую глянуть [это](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fob8oQOjB2Q&list=PLwVBSkoL97Q3phZRyInbM4lShvS1cBl-U&index=6). Да и в целом пересмотреть его уроки, особенно хорош урок про мидлвари

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно добавить `simple_cal_callback.filter()` в `register_callback_query_handler`.

```
dp.register_callback_query_handler(answer_date,
                              simple_cal_callback.filter(),
                              state=customstate)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык